# How do I import my main crate into my test files? Rust doc example doesn't work

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm setting up unit tests for my rust project and using [this guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html).  The documentation says to do something like this, where "adder" is the project name (if I am not mistaken).

tests/integration_test.rs

```
use adder;
mod common;

#[test]
fn it_adds_two() {
    common::setup();
    assert_eq!(4, adder::add_two(2));
}
```

I've done something similar.  My folder structure is tests/users.rs where tests/ is right next to src/ as in the example. Here is what my test file actually looks like:

tests/users.rs

```
use test_project;

#[test]
pub fn create_test() {
    //do things with the modules from main 
}
```

But I'm getting this error:
`no external crate 'test_project'`

As far as I can tell I'm following the documentation to the letter.  Can someone point out what I could be missing here?

Here is my folder structure also:

[image]

I have no problems running a dummy test without the imports `cargo test` so cargo is able to find the tests/ folder without any issues

Here is my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["mcrandall <randall123@protonmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "errormsg"
path = "errormsg/src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["sqlite"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
download_rs = "0.2.0"
futures = "0.3.12"
futures-util = "0.3.12"
oauth2 = { version = "3.0"}
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json", "stream", "blocking"] }
serde = { version= "1.0.123", features = ["derive"] }
serde_derive = "1.0.123"
serde_json = "1.0.61"
simple-server = "0.4.0"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
url = "2.2.0"
uuid = { version = "0.8.2", features = ["v4"] }
```

Comment: You probably made a typo somewhere in your crate name or something, there's nothing wrong with the documentation for this chapter best as I can tell.

Comment: What's the contents of your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @LambdaFairy  I updated my answer with the Cargo.toml.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in your Cargo.toml `name = "test_project"`.
Also, you can only import it if it is a library [Library Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#library).

Looking at your Cargo.toml, the lib section tells cargo that this package exports **one** lib called `errormsg` contained in `errormsg/src/lib.rs`. So `test_project` will not be available for you, because only one lib is allowed per package [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845572/15418858).

There are two solutions to your problem.
You can either make `errormsg` a module which you then can import for example with `test_project::errormsg` in `tests/users.rs`.
Or you can create a separate package and then import it in the Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies]
errormsg = { version = "0.1", path = "./../errormsg" }
```

Another way is to use [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) to group packages, but i'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: It says " A package can have only one library. ".  Is that the issue?  But why would Rust do that?  Shouldn't I be able to create as many libraries as I want to link to?

Comment: A crate/package can only export one library, mainly used via the lib.rs file read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845572/15418858 for why. I will update my answer to hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks the dependency way works.  It was what I was originally going for by using the [lib] declaration.

Comment: I would note in order for me to call `use test_project` in tests/users.rb  I have to list the modules in src/lib.rs and not main.rs as I had them (not shown in my original question).

Answer (score 1):

Anyone encountering this problem (inability to `use` main package in "tests" directory).

This is not the case with the OP but can also arise if you are using PyO3 (or maybe something else, who knows) which requires you to stipulate the "crate-type" under "[lib]" in Cargo.toml.

For PyO3 you have to do this:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

... which will instantly mean that your "tests" directory can't `use` your main project.

The solution:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

... unfortunately this is not a pain-free solution: it apparently means that the library is compiled twice. Much discussion on this and the issues it raises [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6659) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4881). Problems raised several years ago but apparently nothing done about it as yet.